# Attach a type to a function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I got a custom data type schematically defined like this:

```
data Foo = Foo
  { f1 :: Int
  , f2 :: b
  , f3 :: c
  }
```

**What i need to do**

Attach a String to every function recorded in Foo. That was pretty clear in my head that it was trivial due to haskell polymorphism.

---

First try: classes

```
class Value a where
  val :: a -> String
class Query e where
  queries :: (Value a) => [(e -> a, String)]

instance Value Int where val = show
  instance Query Foo where
    queries =
      [ (f1, "function one")
      , (other records of Foo…)
      ]
```

Which doesn't work. I'm not sure i figured out why. But i think ghc expects a function of type (Foo -> a) but gets a function of type (Foo -> Int).
So, the polymorphism doesn't apply here.

---

Second try: pattern matching

```
keyOf :: (Foo -> a) -> String
keyOf f1 = "function one"
keyOf f2 = "function two"
keyOf f3 = "function three"
keyOf _  = "unknown function"
```

I was quite satisfied seeing it would compile. Then, in ghci:

```
λ keyOf f2 = "function one"
```

Can't pattern match against a function name, obviously…

---

**EDIT: Why i need to do it**

Construct a query string like this:

```
"(keyOf f1)=(f1 Foo), (keyOf f2)=(f2 Foo), (keyOf f3)=(f3 Foo)"
```

More generally, fold every function recorded in Foo with the String associated with it, and it's result. Example:

```
exampleFoo :: Foo
exampleFoo = Foo "one" "two" "three"

assocs = [(f1, "function one"), (f2, "function two"), (f3, "function three")]

result == "function one=one, function two=two, function three=three"
```

---

Now, i really wonder if that kind of trick is doable without involving meta-programming (like TemplateHaskell) in haskell. Any options i didn't consider ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a program you'd like to write using the Strings attached to each function?

Comment: yes, i edited the question. Is this clear enough ?

Comment: Afraid not - I can't make out what you mean about the query string. Might be clearer with some sample code or pseudo-code.

Comment: edited. I'm aware this is a bit confused: i know i'm thinking wrong, but i can't think of another design.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for here is an **existential**.

If you define

```
data Selector e where
    Selector :: Value a => (e -> a) -> Selector e
```

(you'll need `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}` at the top of the file)

Then you can define your class `Query` as:

```
class Query e where
    queries :: [(Selector e, String)]

instance Query Foo where
    queries =
        [ (Selector f1, "function one")
        , (other records of Foo…)
        ]
```

The problem with your previous definition was that an implementation of `queries` had to contain functions that could produce *any* `a` type. What you want is that each element of `queries` produces a *specific* type of your choice. That's what the `Selector` type does - it hides that specific type so that you get to choose it rather than the caller of `queries` getting to choose.

In this particular example, the only thing you can do with the `a` type in `Selector` is turn it into a `String` with `Value`, so you could just as well have written:

```
class Query e where
    queries :: [(e -> String, String)]

instance Query Foo where
    queries =
        [ (value . f1, "function one")
        , (other records of Foo…)
        ]
```

However if `Value` were a more complicated typeclass, particularly one that's generally useful, then this flattening would get quite verbose.

Comment: This might be the right answer to the questions, but please don't recommend existentials without telling about their [controversy](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) (I actually tend to promote using existentials in good use cases, but I rather doubt this is one).

Comment: This is a good idea, but `[(Selector e, String)]` will produce a list of `[(Selector Foo, String)]` in instance Query Foo. Then, `Selector f1 :: Selector Int` will not apply in that context.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be `Selector :: Value a => (e -> a) -> Selector e`. But you probably don't need an existential here. The only thing you can do with a value of type `Selector e` is apply the contained function to a value of type `e`, but since the type `a` is existentially quantified, the only thing you can do with the resulting thing is call `val` on it, since that is the only thing you know about `a`: that it is an instance of `Value`. Since `val` simply produces a string, you might as well just have `data Selector e = Selector (e -> String) String` and `queries :: [Selector]`.

Comment: I agree it's not strictly appropriate in this particular context, but Stack Overflow encourages cutting down questions to the essentials. With a more complicated type class but the same fundamental problem, it would be perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you're confusing how `data` works.

By looking at

```
keyOf :: (Foo -> a) -> String
keyOf f1 = "function one"
keyOf f2 = "function two"
keyOf f3 = "function three"
keyOf _  = "unknown function"
```

I think that maybe your data should look like this:

```
data Foo b c = F1 Int | F2 b | F3 c
```

That way, the pattern match would be:

```
keyOf :: Foo b c -> String
keyOf (F1 _) = "function one"
keyOf (F2 _) = "function two"
keyOf (F3 _) = "function three"
```

The `"unknown function"` is not needded, as we are *pattern matching* every possible Foo constructor.

Comment: The Foo data type is composed of 13 records, and i need every single one of them to construct my final query string, so a sum type isn't relevant here, i think.

Comment: In that case, pattern matching may not be the thing you need.